# how to make login async function wrapper around Alamofire.authenticate method in swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire, httpresponse

I have this wrapper class call AutheManager. It has one static function call Login a wrapper around Alamofire.authenticate method.I want to ask how can I implement async and wait for http response to complete move to next logic

```
class AutheManager{
    var manager: Session!
    static func Login(username:String, password:String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ response: DataResponse<Data?>?) -> ()) {

        var response =

        AF.request("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(username)/\(password)")
            .authenticate(username: username, password: password)
            .response { resp in
                response = resp
        }
        return response
    }  
}

@IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton)
    {
        // Check that text has been entered into both the username and password fields.
        guard let newAccountName = emailTextField.text,
            let newPassword = passwordTextField.text,
            !newAccountName.isEmpty,
            !newPassword.isEmpty else {
                showLoginFailedAlert()
                return
        }


        //get response from AutheManager
        response = AutheManager.Login(username: newAccountName, password: newPassword)

    }
```

Comment: Note that you are not actually "login-in" anywhere. You simply obtain a user password credential. This is then provided to Alamofire which uses it _only_ when challenged with Basic Authentication or Digest Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a closure at the end of AutheManager.Login method

```
AutheManager.Login(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, response: [String: Any]?) -> ()) {

    ...

    //call once you get response, for success
    completion(true, response)

    //for failure
    completion(false, nil)
    ...

}
```

Now call this method:

```
AutheManager.Login(username: newAccountName, password: newPassword) { (success, response) in

   guard success, let response = response else { //show message }

   print(response)

   ///move you rest of the code/logic here

}
```